# Apple Notification Service for Jailbreak app

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, jailbreak

I am creating a Jailbreak app that gets installed in /Applications.  No matter what I do I can't seem to get Push Notifications to work.

I have:

- Created the necessary App ID in the Apple Developer console,
- Created all necessary certificates and provisions,
- Installed the above where necessary,
- Signed the app with the corresponding certificate,
- Added the stuff found in the .MobileProvision file to the permissions,
- Beat my head against the wall.

The symptoms are as follows.  I successfully register with APNS and get a Device Token.  The Device Token is successfully sent to my server.  My server successfully connects up with the APNS server, successfully sends a push notification through to the APNS server without any complaint of any kind and my app never, ever receives the Push message.  It just gets lost.  It doesn't matter whether I test with a jailbroken ios 7 device or jailbroken ios 8 device.  As far as I can tell both of these devices are succesfully getting APNS messages for other apps.

I have tried both developer and production settings.

Is there some necessary step for Jailbreak apps that I'm missing that is ordinarily done for you when an app is registered regularly?  Are system apps not capable of being APNS apps (that would seem quite odd)?

Here's some code.  Phone-side (Swift):

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
    if Global.OSVersion() < 800
    {
        application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert
                                                     | UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge
                                                     | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound);
    }
    else
    {
        var types: UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Alert
                                          | UIUserNotificationType.Badge
                                          | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
        var settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types,
                                                                              categories: nil);
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings);
    }
    application.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents();
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData)
{
    let bytes: [Byte] = deviceToken.getBytes();
    var token: String = "";
    for byte: Byte in bytes
    {
        token += NSString(format: "%02.2hhx", byte);
    }
    // code to send token to server goes here...
}

func application(application: UIApplication,
                 didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
{
     let command: String = userInfo["Command"] as String;
     // code to process command goes here...
}
```

Server code (C#):

```
    private bool SendIPhone()
    {
        isSent = false;
        PushBroker pushBroker = new PushBroker();
        try
        {
            pushBroker.OnChannelCreated += pushBroker_OnChannelCreated;
            pushBroker.OnChannelException += pushBroker_OnChannelException;
            pushBroker.OnChannelDestroyed += pushBroker_OnChannelDestroyed;
            pushBroker.OnServiceException += pushBroker_OnServiceException;
            pushBroker.OnNotificationFailed += pushBroker_OnNotificationFailed;
            pushBroker.OnNotificationSent += pushBroker_OnNotificationSent;
            pushBroker.OnNotificationRequeue += pushBroker_OnNotificationRequeue;
            pushBroker.OnDeviceSubscriptionChanged += pushBroker_OnDeviceSubscriptionChanged;
            pushBroker.OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired += pushBroker_OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired;
            pushBroker.RegisterAppleService(new ApplePushChannelSettings(XXXConfig.APNSIsProduction,
                                                                         XXXStatic.APNSCertificate,
                                                                         XXXConfig.APNSPassword));
            AppleNotification notification = new AppleNotification();
            notification.DeviceToken = cloudToPhoneID;
            notification.Payload.Alert.Body = "This is a test";
            notification.Payload.Sound = "Alarm.wav";
            notification.Payload.Badge = 5;
            notification.Payload.CustomItems["content-available"] = new Object[] { "1" };
            notification.Payload.CustomItems["Command"] = new Object[] { "TestCommand" };
            pushBroker.QueueNotification(notification);
        }
        finally
        {
            pushBroker.StopAllServices(); // This will force us to wait until we have sent what's in the queue...
        }
        return isSent;
    }

    void pushBroker_OnNotificationSent(object sender, INotification notification)
    {
        isSent = true;
    }
```

There's lots of code I'm not showing that all works as it's supposed to.  SendIPhone always returns true and it can only be set to true when pushBroker_OnNotificationSent is called.

Entitlements:

```
<dict>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>REMOVEDFORPRIVACY</string>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
    <string>REMOVEDFORPRIVACY</string>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <true/>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>REMOVEDFORPRIVACY</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

What am I missing or is there no path there from here?

Comment: A common mistake with push notification is to use your distribution certificate but sending push to Apple's development push notification server. Are you sure you are settuping your distribution/development environment right ?

Comment: Yup.  I presently only have development certificates for this project and got rid of everything production-related for precisely this reason.  Thanks very the suggestion, but I do think I have this one covered.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I've got a feeling the problem is with how we're building/signing the app.

Comment: Could very well be that Apple does not enable /Applications for push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I don't test it, but if I know Apple allow push notifications in iOS root app folder (just look at "tips" application), so it is maybe problem with certificate, so maybe will this help:

http://www.hackthatphone.com/3x/push.html

This is a tutorial for hackctivated iOS devices, what haven't got valid certificates for push notifications, but it can also help you.

[image]

Comment: Tips app uses local notifications. They are timed notifications from the app itself and not sent via APNS.